# Room Annotations on Top of OrmLite Annotations

Tags: sql, annotations, android-room, ormlite

I am transforming `OrmLite` Library to `Room` Library. Instead of creating new objects for `Room` and converting `OrmLite` objects to it, I am just creating `Room` objects on Top of `OrmLite` objects.

```
@Entity
@DatabaseTable
public class User{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int userId;

    @DatabaseField
    String name;
}
```

Well, I haven't faced any problem, error or any issue while compiling, using etc. My question is "Is it okay to do this way?" or do I have make separate classes and convert from one to another? Or is there anything that I am missing or should consider?

Comment: It looks okay to me.

Comment: Have you tried this way or any suggestion regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good practice, but it works without any problem